# How to detect when pan gesture moves really quickly, rather than finely, to adjust control accordingly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

In my app I have the option for the user to pan upward to adjust a control, but it's a little slow when they pan up really quick, which I'd like to jump a lot more.

```
// If user is panning upwards or downwards, adjust WPM every 8 translations in either direction
if (translation.y<-8 || translation.y>8) {
    // Reset translation so we can see when it exceeds 8 again
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

    // Figure out direction, if pan down, decrease by 5, if up, increase by 5
    int sign = (translation.y > 0) ? -1 : 1;
    WPM = @([WPM intValue] + (sign * 5));

    if ([WPM intValue] >= 200 && [WPM intValue] <= 1500) {
        self.WPMLabel.text = [WPM stringValue];

        self.wordsPerMinute = WPM;

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:WPM forKey:@"WPM"];
    }
}
```

How would I go about changing this to account for faster acceleration?

Answer (score 2):

Use the velocity property on the gesture recognizer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPanGestureRecognizer/velocityInView:

Answer (score 1):

Speed involves time. So each time your code runs, you need to save in an instance variable what time it is on the event's `timestamp`. That way, the *next* time your code runs, you can compare both the translation change *and* the time elapsed to the previous change.

What I would do is experiment with saving three or four previous times and three or four previous locations in an array so that you can take a moving average and damp out speed variations.

Comment: How do I get the event's timestamp?

Comment: Most accurate way: you do all this by writing a UIPanGestureRecognizer subclass. Now you can examine the actual touch, which has a timestamp. - You *could* base your algorithm on the time *now* at each call, but that won't be as accurate as the touch timestamp, which tells when the event actually occurred.